# First @objc after public causes an error in Swift 4

Tags: swift

I ran into this during my Swift 4 conversion and have a simple test case that I am not sure if it is my error or a bug in Swift 4. If I have an @objc identifier as the first property after "public", I get a compile error

```
import Foundation

class ErrorClass: NSObject
{
    public

    @objc let myVal = 0

    let myOtherVal = 1


}
```

This will result in an "Expected declaration" error at the @objc identifier. However, if you reverse the declaration of the two properties like this, everything works fine.

```
import Foundation

class ErrorClass: NSObject
{
    public

    let myOtherVal = 1

    @objc let myVal = 0



}
```

I may be misunderstanding the scope of public. In swift, does it only apply to the declaration after the identifier, or does it scope everything after it like C++? If the former, that would explain my issue as the newline after public would be ignored in the second case making just myOtherVal be affected by the public identifier.

Comment: Im new to Swift but what is "public"? I'm sure you need some deceleration after it !

Comment: Think there's a newline between public and let. So the @objc should be in front of the public.

Comment: Yep, Thanks for the help, it was my misunderstanding of how public scope worked.

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with being the first variable in the class. The `@objc` just needs to precede the access control (`public`). I'm not sure why you have public on the previous line; that seems confusing and I haven't seen that before.

```
class MyClass {
    @objc public let myVar = 0 // compiles
}
```

Comment: OP *may* have thought that `public` applies to *all* following members (as in some other languages).

Comment: I did, and edited my post accordingly, Just asking the question may have helped me figure that out. I was hung up on the C++ way that public scopes. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: No problem; yep, in Swift, that `public` declaration will only apply to the variable, function, class or whatever else precedes it.